# Image Resize and change image Name | Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading, shopping-cart

This is the code in which i am getting error everything else is just fine only images are not being stored in the folder but the image name is being stored in the database.

```
<?php
function add_product()
{
    if($this->input->post('action')=='')
    {
        $this->load->view('admin/add_product');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'product name', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'price', 'trim|required|numeric');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('stock', 'stock', 'trim|required|numeric');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cat_id', 'category', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('desc', 'description', 'trim|required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view("admin/add_product");
        }
        else
        {
            //Here the image manipulation is starting
            $id = $this->admin_model->add_product($this->input->post());
            include("lib/imageManipulation.php");
            include("lib/resize-class.php");
            $type       =   substr(strtolower($_FILES['file']['name']),-4);
            $img_name   =   substr($this->input->post('title'),0,20);
            $img_name   =   str_replace(" ","_",$img_name) ."_". $id;
            $big_image  =   "images/uploads/".$img_name."".$type;
            $med_image  =   "images/uploads/".$img_name."_med".$type;
            $thumbnail  =   "images/uploads/".$img_name."_small".$type;
            copy($_FILES['file'],$big_image);
            $resizeObj = new resize($big_image);
            $resizeObj -> resizeImage(75, 75, 'auto');
            $resizeObj -> saveImage($thumbnail, 100);
            $resizeObj = new resize($big_image);
            $resizeObj -> resizeImage(220, 220, 'auto');
            $resizeObj -> saveImage($med_image, 100);
            $resizeObj = new resize($big_image);
            $resizeObj -> resizeImage(300, 300, 'auto');
            $resizeObj -> saveImage($big_image, 100);
            $this->admin_model->update_image_links($big_image,$med_image,$thumbnail,$id);
            $url = base_url()."index.php/admin/products";
            header("Location:$url");
            exit();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

if anyone can do this without resizing image then also it will be great thanks !

Comment: yes i know but can help me ? @SankarV

Comment: How can we help you without knowing what you're trying to do? In the question, you told us that you're getting an error. What's that error message?

Comment: okay my bad. error is that images are not being uploaded to the folder. but the product data is stored is the database along the image name. and when we view product images are not displayed. @SankarV

Comment: Please check the folder permission and verify the upload path exists. Also do update the question with all necessary details.

Comment: i have given all the permission to that folder. At the time of inserting image into the database with all other fields. all the fields as well as image path is stored. but when you open the folder the image is not visible. @SankarV

Comment: Please show us the error message. Also try to use the codeigniter upload library for uploading images. I don't think `copy($_FILES['file'],$big_image);` will work.